# How to bypass ballast for T8 led

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

Here are pictures of my setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the [led](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-32-Watt-T8-40-Watt-T12-4-ft-Linear-Replacement-Universal-Fit-LED-Tube-Light-Bulb-Daylight-5000K-2-Pack-539163/308350356) light I was using which works without removing the ballast in the other fixture.

But I would still like to learn how to bypass the ballast.

Comment: Any such product will have detailed instructions included. It may be product-specific and there's not much point to us recreating that procedure here. You could look at [documents from such products](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/95/954f3854-e989-441e-b6e5-950dd1f8c6ee.pdf).

Comment: Buy a suitable LED replacement "tube" and follow the instructions provided with it. You cannot bypass the ballast with an LED "tube" that works with a ballast - they expect different things.

Comment: They can be used with ballasts. No rewiring is necessary. But in the home depot comments page, someone used it both with and without ballasts. It seems it is like this [one] (https://www.amazon.com/Hyperikon-Bulbs-Ballast-Bypass-Frosted/dp/B00S5OA1U2/). Here is the installation [guide ](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/C1ga0sru6DS.pdf) for it. The wiring looks like in your link @isherwood. Wouldn't this setup work with most leds that require bypass?

Comment: So it looks like black goes with the reds and blues on the right and white goes with the yellow on the left. Should I ignore the red and blue on the left or connect them with the white?

Comment: I saw that comment, too, but don't consider that a sanctioned strategy. I can't answer that question.

Comment: I doubt you'll get anyone here to approve such a thing. Any legit electrician risks his reputation and/or license doing so.

Comment: Let's say I had the Hyperikon one. Would I ignore the red and blue on the left or connect it to the white?

Comment: The LED light you references requires a ballast, it is not the one that works with or without the ballast.  So what is the purpose of you wanting to learn how to bypass the ballast.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll discover that SE has its own image hosting that shows the pictures embedded in your question instead of making everyone click links to see them. The easier you can make it on the volunteers helping you, the more likely you are to get an answer more quickly.

Comment: Additionally, the most likely answer you're going to get to this question is "don't bypass the ballast" because the products you've chosen won't work that way. If you want to learn for learning's sake, that's good, but maybe choose products for more of a hypothetical question and post using them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the products indicated won't function if the OP does what he's asking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either stay with ballasts (and you might as well use real fluorescents; they're cheaper and the light is better)... or go to ballast-bypass LEDs.

A "Universal" LED will supposedly work either ballast-bypass or with a ballast.

The ballast you pulled was an *entirely modern*, rapid-start T8 ballast. That plus a modern T8 real fluorescent tube is state-of-the-art and better than LED IMO; I'm actually *putting those in*. I assume that ballast had failed?  (if you had been putting T12 tubes in it, that would give poor performance).

With direct-wire LED "replacement tubes", there are two configurations you'll find.

#### Single-ended, direct-wire

This isn't your application, I'm only telling you about it because you need to know *that it exists* so you can be on the lookout for it.

In this case, the tube wants 120V hot + neutral on the 2 pins at one end.  The other end is completely dead and does nothing.

In my opinion single-ended is a bad idea - it's hard to wire, and it puts 120V between the two end pins, and they were never made for that.  Installing a double-ended "tube" may go **kaboom**. *I don't like kaboom, it seems unprofessional.*

#### Double-ended, direct wire, or universal

In this case, the tube wants hot + neutral *at opposite ends of the tube*.  It wants both pins at each end connected.   Generally when you have a Universal LED tube that works either with or without ballast, it will be this type.  (for technical reasons).

This is your case.

This is very simple and straightforward to wire.  All the wires from one end of the fixture, go to Hot.  All the wires from the other end of the fixture, go to Neutral.  To join that many #18 wires, use an orange wire nut.

If you mistakenly install any single-ended "tubes", they just won't work.

*Aren't LED replacement tubes fun?  More confusing than T12 vs T8, and $10 a tube instead of $2!  Supposedly they last forever, but I see a lot of dead ones when I go through big-box stores and look at their ceilings.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The ballast did not fail. I heard it is better to use leds without ballast. So removed it. I guess I should not have. I thought to go with leds since fluorescent ones have mercury in them and they seemed to die too fast in the past and leds use less electricity.

Comment: Harper.  "*That plus a modern T8 real fluorescent tube is state-of-the-art and better than LED IMO*"  I am curious,  what does  "better" mean.

Comment: @Alaska they don’t flicker, they are actually reliable (no Chinese capacitors) and common tubes have higher CRI.also 1/4 the price lol.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the ballast you just hook all the wires from one end of the fitting to black (live) and all the wires from the other end to white (neutral).